# Op amp phase shifter with unity constant gain - How does this circuit shift the phase between -180 and 0?

Tags: operational-amplifier

(Kindly if its possible to understand this circuit w/o \$j\$.. I haven't made peace with complex analysis yet... so I beg your pardon using 
 nasty trig expressions... )

Below circuit is NOT a phase shifter.
As \$R_4\$ varies from \$0\Omega\$ to   \$100\Omega\$, the voltage gain varies from \$-1\$ to \$0\$. I pretty much understand how this circuit works.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcg0Vn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If we simply replace \$R_4\$ by a variable capacitor, this circuit suddenly becomes a **phase shifter** with constant **gain = 1**. I see that input becomes a \$RC\$ lag circuit with fundamental frequency  \$\omega_0 = \dfrac{1}{ R_3C}\$.

As we change the capacitor value, the phase angle \$\phi\$ across the capacitor voltage varies between \$-\pi/2\$ to \$0\$. So the noninverting input at the op amp is \$V_+ = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\omega/\omega_0)^2}}\sin(\omega t + \phi) \$,

where \$\phi = -\arctan(\omega/\omega_0)\$.

Question1 : The input phase \$\phi\$ can only change between \$-\pi/2\$ and \$0\$. So intuitively I expect the output phase also to change with in that window; that is not more than \$\pi/2\$. But my textbook claims that the output phase changes between \$\color{red}{-\pi}\$ to \$0\$. Its almost like the opamp is amplifying the phase difference by a factor of \$2\$. How is this possible ?

Question2 : How can the voltage gain remain constant ? The input voltage \$V_+\$  is a function of \$C\$, it clearly decreases as the capacitor reactance  decreases. Shouldn't this disturb the output voltage ?

Comment: For Question1, I believe I just need to show that the phase of below expression is \$2\phi\$ $$ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\omega/\omega_0)^2}}\sin(\omega t + \phi) - \sin(\omega t) $$

Comment: For DC Xc = 00; So you have a voltage follower with a gain of +1V ( 0 phase shift). But at high-frequency Xc = 0 hence you have an inverting amplifier with the gain equal  -R2/R1 = -1V/V and the phase shift is -180 degrees)

Comment: @G3 Yeah I get the circuit at those two points. Thank you :) When Xc=oo, the noninverting input produces a gain of +2. This superposes with the inverting input gain of -1 to yield +1.

Comment: I don't comprehend how the circuit behaves between those two points. How the voltage gain remains constant at 1 and the phase difference changes..

Comment: If we treat the capacitor as a resistor with resistance  \$X_c\$, then changing this resistor should change the voltage gain. But my textbook says the voltage gain remains 1 no matter what \$X_c\$ is..

Comment: its like \$\phi\$ and \$X_c\$ are working together to keep the gain constant at 1.

Comment: Try to add two sinewaves the first one 1V (-180 degrees) and the second one is 1.4V and -45 degrees phase shift (case when Xc = R3).

Comment: For Vin = 1V and when R3  = Xc the voltage at the output is 1.41V and -45 degrees phase shift. For noninverting amplifier only.  And for inverting case one we have 1V and -180 degrees phase shift the at the output. So to get the real output you need to add them.

Comment: @G36 that produces a phase shift of -90 degrees!  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uspt8at6cm

Comment: -45 degrees at input RC lag circuit and -90 degrees at output. Interesting.. let me play with few more values and see if it gets more convincing... ty :)

Comment: Yes exactly. All pass filter transfer function is  $$\frac{\sqrt{1 +(\omega R C)^2} \cdot e^{-j arctg(\omega R C)}}{\sqrt{1+(\omega R C)^2}\cdot e^{ j arctg(\omega R C)}} = 1 \cdot e^{-2 j arctg(\omega R C)} $$

Comment: That makes clear how the phase difference adds up. I'd very much like to give best answer, may be if you post it as an answer... If you're busy, I understand I don't want to waste more of your time :)

Comment: This is fun ;) https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xklgykifzw

Comment: @G36 I take it that \$arctg\$ is really \$\tan^{-1}\$? or arctangent?

Answer (score 5):

For the DC current and at "low" signal frequency the capacitor reactance is equal to :
\$X_C = \infty  \$

Hence you circuit becomes a noninverting voltage follower with the gain of \$+ 1 V/V\$ with \$0^{\circ} \$ phase shift.

The output voltage is superimposed on this two outputs (\$+2 + (-1) = +1V\$)
Noninverting amplifier with the gain of \$+2\$ and inverting amplifier with a gain of \$-1\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgfY9G.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At high the capacitor reactance is \$X_C = 0\Omega\$

And this time your circuit becomes a textbook example of an inverting amplifier with voltage gain equal to
\$-\frac{R_2}{R_1} = -1\$

So you have gain one but the output voltage is \$-180^{\circ}\$ out of phase shift.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRHUni.png)</sup>

And the transfer function for your circuit (All pass filter) is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpV5F1.png)</sup>

$$ A_V(s) = -\frac{R_2}{R_1} + (1 + \frac{R_2}{R_1}) \cdot\frac{1}{1+ sR_3 C} = \frac{1 - sRC}{1+ sRC}$$

And the magnitude becomes \$ 1\$ (pole is canceled by the zero)

And the phase shift is

\$\phi = -2arc tg (\omega RC) = -2arctan \left( \frac{F}{F_O}\right)\$

Where:

\$F_O = \frac{1}{2 \pi R_3 C}\$

So for the frequency when \$F = F_O\$ the phase shift is

\$ \phi = -2arctan \left( \frac{1}{1}\right) = -2arctan \left(1\right) = -2 \cdot 45^{\circ} = -90^{\circ}\$